# Getting ValueError: Unknown layer: while loading Keras model; how to pass custom_objects argument while training and loading keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to train a BERT text classification model using keras on spam vs ham dataset.

I am getting an error while loading the model. I have saved the model in a h5 format.

I am getting an error `ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer. Please ensure this object is passed to the` custom_objects `argument.`

This is my code for training. Can someone please help

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_balanced['Message'],df_balanced['spam'], stratify=df_balanced['spam'])
    
    
    bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
    bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4")
    
  
    def get_sentence_embeding(sentences):
        preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(sentences)
        return bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)['pooled_output']
    
    # Bert layers
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
    preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(text_input)
    outputs = bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)
    
    # Neural network layers
    l = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name="dropout")(outputs['pooled_output'])
    l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(l)
    
    # Use inputs and outputs to construct a final model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs = [l])
    
    
    model.summary()
   
    
    
    METRICS = [
          tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
          tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
          tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
    ]
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=METRICS)
    
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1)

    model.save("my_h5_model.h5")

 # It can be used to reconstruct the model identically.
    reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("my_h5_model.h5")
```

I have gone through some references and set `compile=False` while loading the model and it has still not worked.

Have also used `https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/snapshot-keras/site/en/guide/keras/save_and_serialize.ipynb#scrollTo=1ae0912f6f9b` for understanding but couldn't exactly find out the changes needed

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this ?